# How to get payout using PayPal API, with only batch_sender_id

Tags: api, paypal

Sometimes the PayPal API fails to give back a `payout_id` but still processes a payment (i.e. because the server is down).

I have some payments that I would like to fetch information for, but only have the `batch_sender_id` (the id that I gave each payment).

Is there a way to get the payment information with PayPal's API? There doesn't seem to be a way to fetch payments without the `payout_id`.

Answer (score 0):

Resubmit with the same batch_sender_id, it should return html code 400 with a link to the resource that contains the previously submitted request. So before making a request to PayPal be sure to store the batch_sender_id so you can re-request later if you do not get a response.